# Continuous Integration/ Delivery Tools (EOL Bamboo)

Tags: continuous-integration, microservices, bamboo, bitbucket-pipelines, continuous-delivery

I've been looking through the site and I have found some information with regards to this topic, but most of the information is old and possibly outdated.
example: [Continuous Integration tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135203/continuous-integration-tools)

**We are:** We're a SaaS product with a microservice (200+) architecture.

**We have:** We currently do our building through bamboo, and we use nexus as an artifact manager with proper versioning. We deploy those artifacts using bamboo to many different machines. For our frontend deployment we build our code through continua and use AWS codedeploy to handle the deployment. We use Bitbucket and Jira for our development. We have done a POC with bitbucket pipelines but we were lacking proper version management there as well as proper environment management. Setting up 10 servers for every repository manually is just something that we don't want to do.

**We want:** Since bamboo is EOL next year and since there are many alternatives with different levels of complexity we are currently unsure about the tools that are most suited to our needs. We are currently running everything on dedicated linux machines, but we want to switch to docker containers in AWS in the near future. Support for running gulp scripts etc. would be great since that could help us move from continua and bamboo to one single solution.

The setup of bamboo has been a struggle in the past due to difficulties with the software itself. A nice balance between features and complexity would be best. Does anybody have experience with one or more of the options out there? Some that come to mind are CircleCi, teamCity, GitLab, Jenkins and AWS codePipeline.

Many thanks,
Kenny

Answer (score 1):

Bamboo doesn't EOL next year, but Atlassian forces to switch from perpetual licenses to DC licences to be renewed every year. You can get discount prices when switch to Server to DC licenses. See details at https://www.atlassian.com/licensing/data-center

Answer (score 0):

I would propose [Kraken CI](https://kraken.ci). It is open-source and can work on-premise but in the cloud as well. In the cloud, it has support for AWS and Azure, and can do autoscaling depending on a number of tasks.
If you are interested please contact me.